# Telegram notifications in Octobercms plugin

Tags: laravel, notifications, telegram, octobercms

I would like to send a telegram message to a specific user at 17:00 using laravel's Telegram notification channel, I however can't seem to get it going. I currently use a cmd command for testing, but keep getting errors and don't know what to do.

Here are my files for the command and notification:

SendNotification.php

```
<?php

namespace Rogier\Lab\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Rogier\Lab\Notifications\DailyTelegram;

   class SendNotifications extends Command
   {

    protected $name = 'lab:notifications:send';
    protected $description = 'Send notifications';
    protected $userid = 919871501;

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {   
        $this->output->writeln('Sending notifications');
        $notification =  new DailyTelegram($this->userid);
        $notification->via()->toTelegram();
        $this->output->writeln('Done');
    }


}
```

and DailyTelegram.php

```
<?php

namespace Rogier\Lab\Notifications;

use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Telegram\TelegramMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


class DailyTelegram extends Notification
{

    protected $userid = 919871501;


    public function via()
    {
        return [TelegramChannel::class];
    }

    public function toTelegram()
    {
        return TelegramMessage::create()
            // Optional recipient user id.
            ->to($this->userid)
            // Markdown supported.
            ->content("Hello there!\nYour invoice has been *PAID*");
    }
}
```

I currently get the error "Call to a member function toTelegram() on array", but I feel like I tried everything, maybe I'm doing it completely wrong. Does anyone know how I should do it?

thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check this article https://codezen.io/sending-telegram-notifications-in-laravel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it wrong. Notifiables have `notify()` method, you should use it:

```
$user->notify(new DailyTelegram);
```

In this example `$user` is `App\User` instance (which is notifiable out of the box).

You should check out both [Laravel's sending notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#sending-notifications) and [laravel-notification-channels/telegram](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/telegram#usage) docs.